# Object of type GuzzleHttp\Client is not callable

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Guzzle for calling api for the first time. My system can download zip on localhost but when I put on live aws, the guzzle cannot work. And the error I get from laravel.log is Object of type GuzzleHttp\Client is not callable {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Object of type GuzzleHttp\Client is not callable. The reason I use new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request is because I want to wait the process of downloading zip completed and then extract to csv file.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using that is causing this error? Maybe a stack trace too?

Comment: $admin_client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$admin_request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET',  $url);
$admin_promise = $admin_client->sendAsync($admin_request)->then(function($admin_response){
//...
});